# Sendgrid emails not sending using C# API

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I have the following code:

```
    public virtual void SendMessage(SendGrid message)
    {
        const string username = "^&*^&";
        const string pswd = "^&*^&*^";

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);

        // Create an web transport for sending email.
        var transport = Web.GetInstance(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        try
        {
            transport.Deliver(message);
            if (transport.IsErrorResponse())
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           //do something
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Which is pretty much the same as what you get in the sample code. The message is a properly formed message (has to, from, html, text) yet when I run it through this code nothing is sent?

`IsErrorResponse` is always false, there is no exception, fiddler shows no traffic?

My account has loads of credit so it's not that I've been hammering it or anything like that. The admin panel leaves a lot to be desired but it's saying that there have been emails sent today - the Email Activity panel seems broken - it shows nothing and sometimes claims to be down atm...

What on earth am I doing wrong?!

Comment: What do you see when you check the status of the emails sent in the Control Panel? Do they show as delivered?

Comment: They don't show at all

Comment: OK so one has shown up but it is saying it has dropped - invalid email address? it's my email address!

Comment: Have you tried using the standard .NET SMTP libraries to send messages? Even if just to try another way? If that works then there might be something wrong with your WebAPI calls, but if it doesn't, maybe something is wrong with your account.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Just saying... Fiddler would help here.

Comment: Since you are seeing an invalid email address message, please post the code that creates the `message` object

Comment: This seems to have just started working - for some reason it doesn't like _my_ email address! It seems to work with other addresses...